# Multiple "or" expressions in an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, angularjs-directive, pug

I am trying to check to see if 1 of 4 conditions are being met on 2 input fields in order to enable a Save button using an AngularJS expression in the `ng-disabled` directive.

The code below will enable the Save button only if the first two conditions are met. So if the user enters any text in the email input field thus making it `$dirty` and `$valid`, the Save button will become enabled. But if the user enters any text into the username input field, the Save button will remain disabled.

How can I get the last two conditions to be seen?

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate>
  <label>Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="user.name" required>
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required>
  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="userForm.email.$pristine || userForm.email.$invalid || userForm.username.$pristine || userForm.username.$invalid">Save</button>
</form>
```

### UPDATE 1

I ended up adding 2 more conditions. It is almost working perfectly now.

When the page loads the Save button is disabled by default because both fields are `$prisitine`. If I delete or add a character to either the username or email field, the Save button will get activated because the field gets `$dirty`. So that works.

The problem starts to happen if I first edit the username. If I create a new valid username and then start editing the email field, I will hit points in the editing process where the email is not valid *e.g.* `email` or `email@` or `email@email.` and at these points we expect the Save button to become disabled but it does not. Somehow once the username is `$valid` it ignores the fact that the email is `$invalid`.

It does not stop there. If I load the page and just start deleting the preloaded email address char by char and hit all the `$invalid` positions, I will see the Save button successfully get disabled at each `$invalid` position. It is driving me crazy.

```
form(name="userForm", ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)", novalidate)

    div.form-group
        label Username
        input.form-control(type="text", name="username", ng-model="user.name", ng-minlength="3", ng-maxlength="23", required)
        div.error(ng-show="userForm.username.$invalid && userForm.username.$dirty")
            p.help-block(ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength") Username is too short.
            p.help-block(ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength") Username is too long.
            p.help-block(ng-show="userForm.username.$error.required") Username is required.

    div.form-group
        label Email
        input.form-control(type="email", name="email", ng-model="user.email", required)
        div.error(ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && userForm.email.$dirty")
            p.help-block(ng-show="userForm.email.$error.required") Email is required.

    button(ng-model="button", ng-disabled="(userForm.username.$error.minlength || userForm.username.$error.maxlength || userForm.username.$error.required || userForm.username.$pristine || userForm.username.$invalid) && (userForm.email.$error.required || userForm.email.$pristine || userForm.email.$invalid)") Save
```

### UPDATE 2

I found a better way to enable the Save button.

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="userForm.$pristine || userForm.$invalid">
```

Works perfect now.

Comment: Not clear conditions - you sayd that user enter any text into username input, save button should be disabled, but you added `required` directive to username input and disable save if username is pristine. Could you clarify conditions for form validation?

Comment: I added an update to my post. Maybe it will help clarify things.

Comment: Maybe we should clean OP, answer and useless comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could toggle the state of your submit button just by checking if the `form` is `$invalid` and inputs are `$pristine`.

So, your inputs would be

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  name="username" 
  placeholder="user name" 
  ng-model="user.name" 
  ng-minlength="3" 
  ng-maxlength="23"
  required></input>

<input 
  type="email" 
  name="email" 
  placeholder="email" 
  ng-model="user.email" 
  required></input>

<button
  type="submit" 
  ng-disabled="(userForm.username.$pristine || userForm.email.$pristine) || userForm.$invalid">Save</button>

<-- ng-disabled="(userForm.$pristine || userForm.$invalid" -->
```

See related Plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/7pkRAn""

Comment: What you wrote makes sense and works. On my local code though, this `(userForm.username.$pristine || userForm.email.$pristine) || userForm.$invalid` expression is not working. The first `||` is acting like an `&&`. I have no idea why that is happening. Makes no sense at all. I've even copied and pasted your expression into my code but that first `||` still acts like an `&&`.

Comment: For now I decided to just use `ng-disabled="userForm.$pristine || userForm.$invalid"` and that works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you want, the condition should look like this:

```
ng-disabled="(userForm.email.$pristine || userForm.email.$invalid) && (userForm.username.$pristine || userForm.username.$invalid)"
```